# MVC another controler or view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing web service for simple game. I use asp.net MVC3. I want to have and "administration board" where administrator can (after selecting one of links) change tables such as "Players" or "Teams" etc.

My problem:

Should I create special controllers for CRUD operation for table Players, Teams? Or should I have only one controller Admin with many methods and views(CreatePlayer(); EditPlayer(); CreateTeam(); EditTeam(); etc)?

Answer (score 3):

Since PLayer and Team are models of your app, you might create Controllers for each. Then maybe you can create an Area for Admin only

Answer (score 0):

it would be easy and efficient to create different controllers for Player and team.

The advantage would be - 
1. you can directly access the LINQ table class to list/edit/delete values( if using linq)
2. Auto generated views can be used for list/create/edit/delete.
3. The code would be loosely coupled.